# Laravel Flash errors - How to check if a checkbox is checked?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to do flash messages in Laravel, now the flash messages work for success messages and error messages on pages that don't have checkboxes.

I have a view called 'deleteappointmentform' which requires the user to check a checkbox and it deletes the checked appointments, however if I don't check any checkbox and click submit it gives me a success message without actually checking if they've checked and checkboxes. I'm trying to get it to display an error message if they don't check any checkboxes

Any help's appreciated, thanks

This is the function that deals with deleting appointments

```
function deleteAppointment(Request $request)
{
    Appointment::destroy($request->appointments);
    Session::flash('successCancelAppointment', 'Appointment cancelled successfully!');
return redirect('all');
}
```

This is my messages blade

```
@if (Session::has('successCancelAppointment'))

<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    <strong>Success: </strong> {{Session::get('successCancelAppointment')}}
</div>
    @endif



@if (count($errors) > 0)

<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <strong>Errors:</strong>
    <ul> 
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{$error}}</li>
        @endforeach

    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

This is my deleteappointmentsblade

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title', 'Cancel Appointment')
@section('content')

<form action="{{url('deleteappointment')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
     @foreach ($appointments as $appointment)
        <div>
            <label> {{$appointment->user->firstname}} {{$appointment->user->surname}}</label>
            <label>Has an appointment at: {{$appointment->time}}</label>
            <label>On: {{$appointment->date}}</label>
            <label>With Dr: {{$appointment->doctor->surname}}</label>

            <input type='checkbox' value='{{$appointment->id}}' name='appointments[]'/>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Cancel Appointments">
</form>


@endsection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
function deleteAppointment(Request $request)
 {     $rules=array(
            'appointments'=>'required'
        );
      $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if($validator->fails())
      {
         $messages = $validator->messages();
         $errors = $messages->all();
         return redirect()->back()->withErrors($errors);
      }
      Appointment::destroy($request->appointments);
   Session::flash('successCancelAppointment', 'Appointment cancelled 
      successfully!');
   return redirect('all');
}
```

Comment: That works excellent, thankyou, please could you briefly explain what the rules and validator part of the code is doing?

Comment: please refer this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation